# Admob low fill-rate in Iran

Tags: ios, iphone, admob, ads

I developed IOS app and it uses Admob for monetizing advertisements. It seems there is a problem with the implementation. My ad fill rate is about 2% to 3% which is very low. I tried 3rd party network named InMobi. No success.

My users are in Iran. Anybody have same issue or any alternative solution?

Comment: Try other networks until you find network with better fill rates. Alternatively look for local advertisers

Comment: I encouraged my users to use vpn while playing my game. This way increased my match percent to 8%.

Answer (score 1):

Google must comply with sanctions imposed by the United States Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC). As a result, AdMob is not available to users in the following countries or territories:

Crimea
Cuba
**Iran**
North Korea
Sudan
Syria

From: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6163675?hl=en